# Spring Batch Multithreading stuck without any exception output

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am implementing Spring Batch multithreading for some daily process. Item reader, Item processor and  item writer are all bean(singleton). Also I am using Hibernate and spring data jpa for db access. For thread, I am using threadpooltaskexecutor.

Thread will hang for no reason, probably I don't know the root cause. Right now, in  log,  hibernate will stuck at either select or insert statement and just  hang  there forever. I  don't really know the reason. For transaction, I have  required_new and read_committed for propagation and  isolation. Everything else is just default from Spring Boot.

I am  processing 20k jsons, size might differ, but some are big. I can't share the whole code because I don't know where the problem is. Basically in item processor, I have few sync blocks to handle the business logic.

For this  question, I just want to know what are the possible reasons? Because Java doesn't give any information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without code it is hard to say what might be the problem .You need to dig down exactly where its getting hanged. Possible reasons are

1. In reader select query is taking long time. (May be due to improper indexing or table might have locked). You can add more logs in reader to check exactly which record/s is causing this.
2. If you are doing any DB operations in ItemProcessor, add logs add check.
3. In writer, insertion might be taking long to complete writing.

Comment: item reader does the read, it  just read from a single table. The problem happens  in item processor. When I switch from multithreading to partitioning. Everything works fine for now, not seeing  any error or halt. Not sure  why.

Comment: @gamewu It is difficult say what exactly the issue is without any code or log. Please accept the answer if it has helped you.